# GTK-WARNING cannot open display on mac

Tags: c++, macos, gtk

I'm following the GTK tutorial and already installed all the dependencies and all is working although when I run my code I get this error:

```
(process:34571): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.

(main:34571): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

my main.cpp is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    std::cout << "hello GTK!!" << std::endl;

    GtkWidget *window;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_widget_show(window);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

how can I solve this?

Comment: What version of GTK+ is this and how did you install it?

Comment: 2.0 and used homebrew. I'm having no problem including gtk and compiling the code. The cout is printing to console just fine.

Comment: You need to run X11.app in /Appliations/Utilities; GTK+ 2.0 only supports X11 on Mac OS X.

Comment: yep, it works when I run it inside X11 terminal. Is there a way to call it without opening the X11 terminal explicitly?

Comment: You can now use [Gtk's Quartz backend](http://www.gtk.org/download/macos.php).

Answer (score 0):

make sure to download and install or update if needed xquartz from https://www.xquartz.org/. restart the mac.