# How to compile code with gtk.h in C under MacOS?

Tags: c, macos, include, gtk3, macports

I have 40 years of computer experience but I'm self taught and I'm intermediate at the C language so I'm not going to know more advanced topics.  I'm trying to learn to use GTK+ by watching [these YouTube videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEs_0O72adQBUpcPJv7dKaElGwyzVljtk) but they're for Linux.  I want my programs to be cross-platform to Windows and Mac.  I have a 2019, Intel, Macbook Pro with Ventura (MacOS 13.4.1).  I haven't been able to find a tutorial on how to install the GTK+ header files on Ventura.  The best I could do was to use MacPorts.  MacPorts put gtk.h into "/opt/local/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h".  I used this code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

// gtk codes goes here

gtk_main ();

return 0;
}
```

and this compile instruction:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o start start.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

but got this error:

```
zsh: command not found: pkg-config 
zsh: command not found: pkg-config 
In file included from start.c:1: /opt/local/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:30:10: fatal error: 'gdk/gdk.h' file not found
#include <gdk/gdk.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~ 
1 error generated.
```

Changing the include directive to #include "/opt/local/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h" gave me the same error.  What do I need to do to get the code to compile?

Comment: Your primary need is not for the headers, it is for the development *libraries*.  The headers are an adjunct to that.  MacPorts, homebrew, or fink are all fine sources for UNIX-y software for Mac that Apple does not provide, including GTK.  Your best bet is probably to choose just one of these.

Comment: The primary issue for your build appears to be that you're trying to rely on `pkg-config`, but you don't actually have it.  I expect (but have not checked) that you can get it, too, from MacPorts.

Comment: What's up with the ` symbols? Shouldn't that be `'` or `"`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger You were right, the answer is to use MacPorts to install pkg-config.  The program will compile but if you run it you'll get, "Gtk-WARNING**:" and "cannot  open display:" and the program won't start unless you also install a seperate program called XQuartz from https://www.xquartz.org/index.html .  There's a post about it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29447046/gtk-warning-cannot-open-display-on-mac. Since it's your answer, why don't you post it as one so you can get credit for it?

Comment: @Lundin The Dartmouth tutorial on GTK (https://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~cs23/gtk.html) has a PDF file (https://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~cs23/gtk_tutorial.pdf) that says on page 8:

Take care to type backticks, not apostrophes

• backticks are instructions to the shell to execute and
append the output of the enclosed command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compilation command you are using depends on the `pkg-config` command, which MacOS does not provide by default.  You should be able to install it from MacPorts.

As you already discovered, Gtk is X11-based, so you will also need an X server.  MacOS has not provided an X server for years, but Apple did spin off the one it once provided into a separate project, XQuartz, which is still maintained.

Comment: Good job, hopefully this will help everyone who tries to write a cross-platform app.